# Using ng-repeat, ng-click and $scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to set up a tabbed nav bar that displays content in a div based upon a clicked tab. I'm using ng-repeat in my HTML like so:

HTML:

```
<ul class ="sidebar-nav">
  <li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="category.method()">{{category.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

But rather than it calling a method to set it to the active tab when it is clicked, I am seeing that all of the tabs are listed when the page loads and the active tab does not change upon being clicked. Here is my angular:

```
$scope.setTab = function(activateTab) {
  $scope.tab = activateTab;
  console.log(activateTab);
}; 

$scope.categories = [
  {
  "name" : "Common Tools",
  method : $scope.setTab(1)
  },
...
```

I tried to set the tab using an anonymous function, as well as using an "id" number inside the individual categories, but I get the same behavior. Any advice?

Comment: Are you saying you tried `method: function() { $scope.setTab(1); }`? Also, where is `$scope.tab` being used to determine the active style/class?

Comment: I did not try it like that but it appears to be setting the tab correctly now. I was hoping to use it in the HTML on a div using ng-show. Is that possible? I'm learning angular and I think that I realized how scope is used through this example a little better, but how would I go about using ng-show now with the active tab?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this ...

**HTML**

```
<ul class ="sidebar-nav">
  <li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="setTab(category.id)" ng-class="{active: category.id === tab}">{{category.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.setTab = function (activateTab) {
  $scope.tab = activateTab;
}; 

$scope.categories = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Common Tools"
}];
```

Comment: Was it necessary to post a near identical copy of my answer?

Comment: @ClintPowell There is less than 3 minutes between the two.

Answer (score 5):

Update your code to:

```
$scope.setTab = function(activateTab) {
  $scope.tab = activateTab;
}; 

$scope.categories =[{"name":"Common Tools"}];
```

And in your HTML:

```
<ul class ="sidebar-nav">
  <li ng-repeat="category in categories" 
      ng-click="setTab(category)" 
      ng-class="{active: tab == category}">{{category.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can set your styles for the `.active` class for your tabs.